# Reload main window's variable in popup window

Tags: apache-flex, popup

I have a quesion about how to access main window's variable from popup window.

I create a popup window in the main window, and pass variable "content" to this popup window as following code:

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    // ......
    popwin = PopUpManager.createPopUp(UIComponent(parentApplication), PopupWindow, true) as PopupWindow;
    popwin.parentView = this; // parentView is an IFlexDisplayObject
    popwin.content = content;
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(popwin);
    // ......
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

In the popwin, I changed value of "content" variable, but I want reset the value of "content" when click "Reset" button on popwin.

I know, I dispatch an event in popwin window, and add listener in main window
Code fragment in popwin:

```
parentView.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.RESET) );
```

Code fragment in main window:

```
addEventListener(CustomEvent.RESET, resetContent);

public function resetContent():void{
    this.content = loadContent();
}
```

But the value of "content" doesn't reset in popwin.

Is there anything I missed?

Is there any other method to update "content" in popup window?

=====================Question update at 15/8/2011==============================

I use following code in popwin's createComplete() function:

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty(textInput, "text", content, "name", false);
```

When I change the text value of textInput and reset the content, it load original value of content.name in my trace log, but the text value of textInput doesn't revert to original value.

If I use following code instead BindingUtils.bindProperty:

```
[Bindable]
public var content:Content;
......
<mx:TextInput id="textInput" text="{content.name}" />
```

And do the same action, the content.name is reload in my trace log, but the text value set to blank in textInput.

Is anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
popwin = PopUpManager.createPopUp(UIComponent(parentApplication), PopupWindow, true) as PopupWindow;
popwin.parentView = this; // parentView is an IFlexDisplayObject
popwin.content = content;
BindingUtils. bindProperty(popwin, "content", this, "content", false, true);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(popwin);
```

Comment: I thought bindProperty may work, but it not for me. The "content" is an Object in the popwin, and it will be the dataProvider of a repeater Component. When I change the text value of that repeater component and try reset it, it doesn't load the original value.

Comment: I'm trying to find where and why the data provider doesn't update when resetting.  Maybe due to other reason. But if anyone have some suggestion, please post your comment here. Thank you very much.

Comment: In the line `this.content = loadContent()` you change the pointer of `this.content` to an other area of memory but pointer of popup's `content` property still points to the previous area. And data binding isn't work in ActionScript. You can invoke binding with `BindingUtils` and I can't understand why this solution is not for you with your architecture where binding suits your needs perfectly?

Comment: Comment is so difficult for editing complex content, so I updated my quesion.

Comment: I suppose you should extract your update in a separate question.

Comment: I accept this answer, because it really works for updating variable in popup window from main window.  Although, it doesn't resolve my problem. Because my problem is due to other reason. I will open a new quesion.

Answer (score 0):

Just set content again.

```
public function resetContent():void{
    if (popwin != null){
     popwin.content = this;
    }
}
```